# I couldn't get google Ads for my website Tamil content. How can i get google ads for tamil content?

Tags: adsense

I have running own website enabled google Adsense. I couldn't get Ads for tamil content. How would i get google ads for Tamil content. The ads can displays well for the English content of my website the problem of facing my end is only belonged to Tamil contents which i post a news in Tamil it will affect my entire google ads.

I have seen some other sites which is "http://tamil.oneindia.com/" & "http://www.dinamalar.com/" they are using Tamil content and Working the google adsense well.

Please someone help me out this problem.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please try adgebra platform. visit http://publisher.adgebra.in/ they are largest Indian regional language ad network.

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

It is because, Google Adsense did not support Tamil until Feb 9, 2018. You can try now.

Info from Google Blog.
https://adsense.googleblog.com/2018/02/AdSense-now-supports-Tamil.html